# Merge an array variable with a variable using if Batch File

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I have a little for loop:

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%e in (include#.forms) do (
set/a C+=1
set In!C!=%%e
)
```

But I want to use an another for loop to read it:

```
for /l %%N in (1 1 !C!) do (
for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%a in (!In!C!!) do.....
```

But how would you take an array's special Variable and a Variable you already used in an array. Because, !In!!C! will turn out !In! and !C! not merged but separated.

Comment: That `for /f` loop should be calling `!In%%N!` instead of `!In!!C!` unless you want it to read the same element in the array over and over.

Comment: Yes, that could be a way to not use a variable, but how would I put it into an IF statement. Like: if `"!In!!C!"=="...."` but `!In!!C!` turns into In + C not !In1! or !In2!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this out myself lol. To merge to variables ex:

```
set 1:1=Hello
set array_row=1
set array_id=1
```

We want to echo `!%array_row%:%arrow_id%!`, but that doesn't work. We will use a for statement:

```
for /f %%x in ("!array_row!") do for /f %%y in ("!array_id!") do echo !%%x:%%y!
```

`%%` variables are executed first so we will use that. The ouput before echoed will be `!1:1!`.

The reason I want this because I was dealing with arrays ex:

```
set file1_name=Text.txt
set file2_name=Run.bat
```

I wanted to compare if the user input equals a file (their not actually files) to run. For this we will (to echo them)

```
for /L %%C in (1 1 2) do echo !file%%C_name!
```

Since it's an array we use a for /L(loop) and not a for /f(read). Both use a %% variable.